# Blender 4 - Displacement shader not working

Tags: displacement

Don't know if it is a regression bug or what not, but **I dont even find the settings for this**

- I tried switching to cycles, same problem
- I tried contrasting my map image, nothing
- I used subdivisions
- I edited and subdivided the standard cube....absolutely nothing

how do I enable that displacement ?

thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: Cycles only so far, and you've to activate displacement in the material settings. Have you did it?

Comment: as I said, no displacement menu in the material settings, check the picture

Comment: As I said, Cycles only for displacement https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/components/displacement.html#displacement-only

Comment: ok so no displacement for me then, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I just confirmed that displacement works fine in *Cycles* in Blender 4.0. The material setting to enable it only shows up in *Cycles*, so make sure to switch render engines first. Then, set *Material Properties > Settings > Surface > Displacement* to *Displacement Only* or *Displacement and Bump* based on your needs. Please note that your object needs to have enough geometry to be displaced. Typically, you will add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier set to *Simple* with enough *Levels*.